# Read File From Directory with Multiple Files of the Same File Extension in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, automation, xsd

I am trying to parse a specific XSD file (File1.xsd) located in the file path shown below using Python, but there are multiple files in that file path with the same file extension (File2.xsd and File3.xsd).   File1.xsd will be used to validate an xml against the File1.xsd schema, but I am unable parse the file path for just this single XSD file (per the "xml_validator" function).

Does anybody know how to tweak/enhance the code to look for only File1.xsd and otherwise apply the same technique for a directory with multiple files of the same file extension - The output will be a Boolean expression per the "is_valid" function, any assistance is most appreciated!

```
import os
import glob
import lxml
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XMLSchema
import xmlschema

path = "C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\Data\\"

def validation():
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")):
        with open(filename,'r') as f: 
            xml_file=lxml.etree.parse(f)
            xml_validator=lxml.etree.XMLSchema(file="<path_to_File1.xsd">))
            is_valid=xml_validator.validate(xml_file)
            print(is_valid)
        return

validation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the file you need as validator (`File1.xsd`), parse it, and then loop through the `.xml` files:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\Data\\"

def validation():
    with open(f"{path}File1.xsd", 'r') as filxsd:
         xml_validator = XMLSchema(file=filxsd)
    for fil in glob.glob(f"{path}*.xml"):                 
        with open(fil, 'r') as f: 
            xml_file = lxml.etree.parse(f)
            is_valid = xml_validator.validate(xml_file)
            print(is_valid)
```

Comment: panadestein - I first need to parse the xml and then validate it against File1.xsd, where both the xml and xsd files are in the same directory (C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\Data).  I don't want to have to hard-code the .xsd file name, but rather parse the files from a single directory and delineate File1.xsd from the other .xsd files in the same file path - Your insights are most appreciated!

Comment: @mdl518 I have edited my answer. If I have well understood, you need to parse `File1.xsd` and then the rest of the `.xml` files right? Then do both things independently.

Comment: panadestein - I think your solution is very close to what I need.  However, I think ultimately we will have to hard-code the full path of the .xsd into the "xml_validator"; I think it will be acceptable for the purposes of my project and I cannot think of a more slick way that intelligently delineates between filenames with the same file extensions.  I will add the following edit to the original script, and mark as complete - Thanks again for your help! 

 " xml_validator=lxml.etree.XMLSchema(file=<path_to_File1.xsd")"

Comment: @mdl518 no problems, I am glad it helped. Take into account that if you do the import `from lxml.etree import XMLSchema` then you cannot do `lxml.etree.XMLSchema(file=fil)` but rather `XMLSchema(file=fil)` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the xml_validator line with this:
xml_validator=lxml.etree.XMLSchema(os.path.join(path,filename.replace(".xml",".xsd")))

I assume that your filenames do only include the string ".xml" at the end, if you have filenames like "my.xmlfile.xml", you should replace only the last ".xml" instance.

Comment: Stavros, the xml_validator function must take an "xsd" file (File1.xsd) as the input and not replace with xml.  The issue I am having is that I just want to read only File1.xsd from the file path and not File2.xsd or File3.xsd.  I am not sure how to parse the file path for one file while others in the same path have the same file extension, so that is where I am getting stuck!